# Before Grunt Owl Carousel Work - After it doesn't - no errors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm going nuts - I have tried to solve this problem for a month.

I have yeoman webapp setup.
I have multiple Owl-Carousels on same page - with some added js code to make a rotating cursor. See my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ftpptf/ygkb2za6/

Everything works with Grunt Serve.
After 'Grunt --debug --verbose' no errors and owl carousel incorrectly displays all images at once and on top of each other.

No errors in console either.

I suspect it has something to do with my bower.json file. as you can see I added overrides for the owl carousel. But doesn't seem to work either, I'm no expert - so not sure I have done it properly though.

```
{
"name": "ptf2000",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.5",
  "modernizr": "~2.8.3",
  "jquery": "^2.2.0",
  "icomoon-sassy": "^1.0.0",
  "OwlCarouselBower": "^1.3.4"
},
"overrides": {
  "bootstrap-sass": {
   "main": [
     "assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss",
     "assets/fonts/bootstrap/*",
     "assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"
   ]      
},
"OwlCarouselBower": {
  "main": ["dist/assets/owl.carousel.css", "dist/assets/owl.theme.css",         "dist/owl.carousel.min.js"]
},
"OwlCarouselBower": {
  "main": [
    "owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css",
    "owl-carousel/owl.theme.css",
    "owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"
     ]
   }
 },

  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: So why you duplicate this?

Comment: I just did it in a desperate attempt to solve the problem - to be hones I don't know if it has anything to do with the problem itself. I have just tried any troubleshoots out there - and i could understand that some people used these overrides to deal with some owl carousels that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed this problem. I made a whole new yeoman setup with gulp instead of grunt. Apparently it worked. Unfortunately I am not able to come closer to an explanation since I have no idea what caused the problem.